# How to measure the distance between a word and the right-margin

Tags: javascript, html

[image: examp]

This is the distance i would need to measure somehow.

Why i need it?

```js
//↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ No ‑ breaking hypen
.replace(/\b((\w+?)\-)((\w+?\b[\.\,\?\!\”\)\:\;]*)(\-(\w+?\b[\.\,\?\!\”\)\:\;]*))?)/g, (_, a,b,c,d,e,f)=>{

const [aaaaaaa,niunumber] = /([\d\.]+(px|em|rem|pt|pc|cm|mm|in|\%|ch|vh|vw|vmin|vmax|ex))/.exec(getComputedStyle(document.body,null).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
const can = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
const ttext = _;
const sWidth = +window.innerWidth;
ctx.font = niunumber + " " + "Serif";
const leength = ctx.measureText(ttext).width;
const ggh = 26 ;//% of screenWidth allowed//max value: 100//
const wordWidth= sWidth * (ggh/100);
    const wtot2 = parseInt(c.length);
    const wtot3 = parseInt(d.length);
    const wtot4 = wtot2 - wtot3;
    if(wtot4 > 0 && leength < wordWidth + 0.01)
        return `${b}\‑${d}\‑${f}`;
    else
        if(leength < wordWidth + 0.01 && wtot4 === 0)
            return `${b}\‑${d}`;
        else
            return `${_}`;
})
//↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
;
```

This the script i made to locate words with hypens and replace the ones that occupy under a certain % of the screen width with a no-breaking hypen.
I would like to know a method to measure that space in the image so that i could make this (the following image) break the line based on the distance between the word and the right margin.
[image: examp2]

in the image the word "grotto-" is whitin the limits I set (under 26% of screen width) so i would like to make it break.

How to do it?

Comment: Have you checked out the [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) setting in CSS? That may be a better approach, as what you're trying to do in the question will be extremely complex to implement

Comment: It sounds like you've settled on an approach to solve a problem that has better solutions. As @RoryMcCrossan said, this is going to be difficult and imprecise when you could take other approaches like looking into `word-break`, using `text-align:justify`, and setting padding.